# Java - Calculating the sum of all even numbers up to a certain number

Tags: java, swing, numbers, sum

How do I calculate the sum of all the even numbers up to a certain number entered by the user using Java?

Comment: What have you tried? Generally I like to put as much work into an answer as the writer put into the question. Right now you are just having us do your homework for you

Comment: I firstly just tried to get it to add the sum of all the numbers between 0 and a certain number entered, so I wrote of the sequence of numbers and tried to find a formula that linked the input numbers to the output, and then tried the same for the even numbers only. I'm not asking you to do my 'homework', I'm just genuinely stuck and confused as computing isn't a strong point of mine...

Answer (score 2):

The naive solution would be to start from 0 and keep adding even numbers like this:

```
public static int square (int x)
{
    int sum= 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= x; i+=2) sum += i;
    return sum;
}
```

but you don't have to do this. This is a simple arithmetic sequence and to calculate the sum you can use the formula `sum= n(a1 + an)/2` where `a1` is the first term, 'an' is the last term and `n` is the total number of terms in the sequence.

for you `a1` is 2, `an` is the parameter and you can calculate `n` by dividing the parameter (rounded down to closest even number) by 2.

This way your function will be:

```
public static int square (int x)
{   
    //you can do error checking if you want, x has to be non negative

    if( (x%2) !=0) x--;

    //x is guaranteed to be even at this point so x/2 is also an int
    int sum= x/2 *(1+x/2);

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: In the question `all the even numbers up to and including a number entered by the user` -- the number entered could be odd, but should still be added.

Comment: I agree the wording is not very precise but I don't interpret the question this way. in any case, if that behaviour is required, the modification required would be trivial

Comment: agreed. If it was my project I would ask for clarification anyways. Nice equation nonetheless

Comment: Thanks so much! Yeah in the question i meant that for example if i entered the number 5, it would then add 2 and 4 together.

Answer (score 1):

The trick to this question is "even numbers". By using % (the modulus operator) you can find these numbers easy. If you are curious about Mod, check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6zfzfy7(v=vs.90).aspx

Using the square method you currently have and making a few modifications you can achieve the solution.

```
static int square (int x)
{
    int result = x;

    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
         if(i%2 == 0){
             result += i
         }   
    }

    return result;
}
```